# Get location of a word in an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

So we have an array of strings with the names of fruits. Lets say you want to know in which place in the array the word "Peach" is (returned as an integer). How would you achieve this? I tried finding a related article to this but could not find one.

```
 fruits = new String[] {"Peach", "Orange", "Banana", "Plum", "Apple", "Strawberry", "Mango", "Kiwi"};
```

Comment: Iterate over it and compare the Strings if you find it return the position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really need to use an array for your use-case ? Most of the time it is more comfortable working with collections :

```
List<String> fruits = Arrays.asList("Peach", "Orange", "Banana", "Plum", "Apple", "Strawberry", "Mango", "Kiwi");
int i = fruits.indexOf("Apple");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add some NPE checking, but generally:

```
int getIndex(String word, String[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].equals(word)) {
             return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: It's common practice to return -1, look at indexOf for List

Answer (score 2):

So, first things first.

The variable fruits is not a String, it's an Array of Strings. Therefore, you can simply iterate over it with a for loop searching for "Peach" with the String.equals() method.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] fruits = new String[] {"Peach", "Orange", "Banana", "Plum", "Apple", "Strawberry", "Mango", "Kiwi"};

        int out = -1;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < fruits.length ; i++) {
            if (fruits[i].equals("Peach")) {
                System.out.println("\"Peach\" was found at index: " + i);
                out = i;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Hope this answers the question :)

Edit: Seeing how some posters have suggested Binary Search for solving the problem, I want to address the potential issue that the Binary Search Algorithm requires you to sort the list. Therefore, it will change the index that you were originally looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this using the `collections`:

```
List<String> f = Arrays.asList("Peach", "Orange", "Banana", "Plum", "Apple", "Strawberry", "Mango", "Kiwi");
int i = f.indexOf("Apple");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the available options.
You can also use a search algorithm, like [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).
Usually you want to do this if your array gets large.

```
 Arrays.sort(fruits);
 int position = Arrays.binarySearch(fruits, "Peach");
```

Note: The `sort()` is needed, because most search algorithms only work on sorted arrays.

Comment: why sort before search?

Comment: Because binary search is a dichotomic algorithm which requires the array to be sorted.

Comment: so it's going to return different value than it should without sorting

Comment: Yes, that's the case.

Answer (score -1):

Although the solution shown by maszter works, it is a linear search so isn't as efficient as some of the other search methods. These include binary search etc. and they are provided with the class `java.util.Arrays` in Java with the syntax:

```
Arrays.binarySearch(array, word); //A much faster approach
```

If more speed is necessary and searching is the main use of the array, I would recommend using a HashMap or HashSet instead.

Comment: While it is true that binary search is fast, it is important to remember that this algorithm requires data to be sorted into ascending order. Example: for array like `String[] arr = {"c","b","a"};` result of `Arrays.binarySearch(arr, "c")` is `-4`.

Comment: +1 Pshemo. As the complexity of the best sort algorithms is O(n log n) when the array has no particular properties, this solution is actually slower than a linear search if the array is not sorted.